# Subset a dataframe using 2 columns with a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")
Measurement <- c('Length',NA,NA,NA,'Length','Length',NA,NA,'Length')
PT <- c(27,35,38,22,35,39,7,15,33)
df <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,PT)
Limit <- 25
```

I am trying to subset this dataframe using the limit as the condition so that I exclude any data that has a ("PT" value > limit AND Measuremnent = NA).

Note: However I still want to include any data that has PT > Limit but with a Measurement type in it. In this case, its the length.

I am trying to do it this way but I get an error

```
df3 <- !subset(df3,df3$PT >= Limit & df3$Measurement == '')
```

My desired Output is

```
  ID Measurement PT
1  A      Length 27
2  D        <NA> 22
3  E      Length 35
4  F      Length 39
5  G        <NA>  7
6  H        <NA> 15
7  I      Length 33
```

I know this is pretty simple but I missing the logic somewhere. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you looking for `df[!is.na(df$Measurement) | df$PT < Limit,]`?

Comment: @josilber, fantastic. Exactly does what I wanted. I took your solution to my bigger data set and works like charm. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do

```
df[with(df, !(PT> Limit & is.na(Measurement))),]
#  ID Measurement PT
#1  A      Length 27
#4  D        <NA> 22
#5  E      Length 35
#6  F      Length 39
#7  G        <NA>  7
#8  H        <NA> 15
#9  I      Length 33
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(!(PT > Limit & is.na(Measurement)))
```

Comment: Wanted a dplyr solution as well. Thanks much akrun.